# Let binding in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I want to print the following output.

```
import Data.Char  
  
main = do  
    output = map toUpper "helloworld"
    putStrLn output
```

It failed with the error message.

```
test.hs:4:12: error:
    parse error on input ‘=’
    Suggested fix:
      Perhaps you need a 'let' in a 'do' block?
      e.g. 'let x = 5' instead of 'x = 5'
  |
4 |     output = map toUpper "helloworld"  
  |
```

However, if I use let binding, it works. Why?

```
main = do  
    -- it works
    let output = map toUpper "helloworld"
    putStrLn output
```

Comment: That's a confusing question. Why do you think it should work without the `let`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inside `do`, the syntax does require one to use `let variable = expression`, as the error message suggests. There's not much to say about that syntactical choice.

One might wonder why `variable = expression` (without `let`) was not chosen as the correct syntax. It's hard to guess the rationale, but note that

```
foo = do
   let x1 = e1
   let x2 = e2
   ...
```

and

```
foo = do
   let x1 = e1
       x2 = e2
   ...
```

are *both* valid. The main difference is that the latter allows both `e1` and `e2` to refer to both `x1` and `x2`, which is useful for mutually recursive definitions. By contrast, in the former `do` block `e1` can not refer to `x2`.

The point is that after a `let` one can write a block of defining equations, and not just a single one.

Anyway, the difference explained above is not that important in practice since we do not use mutual recursion that often. Still, it is there.

Comment: It's strange because it looks like you gave the answer, but then you say "it's hard to guess the rationale": if there were no `let` binding, it would be impossible either to have mutually recursive definitions, or to shadow variables while using previous ones (like in `let x = x + 1`)

Comment: @jthulhu Shadowing like that works in ocaml but not in Haskell where every `let` is recursive, though. BTW, I only said it's hard to guess because I'm not completely sure about what was the goal of the designers. Also, given that shadowing doesn't work, one could have used a policy like "put all the adjacent equations in the same block" always enabling recursion, in principle. I feel more options exists, so it's not a completely clear-cut case (IMO).